# Angular transclude not working as intended?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do a very simple transclude causing a div with the text "hi" to appear after an input, just to see that it is working before moving forward. Here is the markup I am using the directive on:

```
 <input id="zipCodeField" validated-field />
```

The directive definition has `transclude: true` and uses this template:

```
<div>
    <div ng-transclude></div>
    <div>hi!</div>
</div>
```

I would expect the input element to be transcluded into where the ng-transclude is in the template. Instead, I am getting this result:

```
<input id="zipCodeField" validated-field>
    <div>
        <div ng-transclude></div>
        <div>hi!</div>
    </div>
</input>
```

What am I doing wrong here? This is in keeping with the examples I have seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding `transclude`.  As I understand it, `transclude` takes the *contents* (think `innerHTML`) of the element and puts them inside the `ng-transclude` in the directive's template.  It *doesn't* take the whole element itself (`outerHTML`).

So, in your example (assuming the directive is `validated-field`), you'd do:

```
<div validated-field>
    <input id="zipCodeField" />
</div>
```

This should result in the `input` getting dropped into the directive inside the `ng-transclude` element.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm trying to find a way to make it work the other way. Hmm. Is this not what the old `replace` attribute was for?

Comment: @Aerovistae -- sort of, but it wasn't specific to transclude.  `replace` would remove the element where the directive was "called" and put the directive template in it's place making the DOM one level shallower.  Practically, I think they decided that the extra level of nesting didn't matter and it was probably a performance or code maintenance problem so they decided to drop it.

Comment: I found my solution! https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/wPkdNKW9flQ Have to do this without using transclude.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but at first sight shouldn't the directive template look like

```
   <div>
        <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
        <div>hi!</div>
   </div>
```

?

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude